# Need advice about design Restful with user role

Tags: java, rest

I'm confusing about design restful for my API.

I have 2 roles are end-user and backend(admin). With backend role, i can access any resources of user

An user can have many orders.

So I defined base on **users** resource

```
GET /users/{userID} -- get User Information
GET /users/{userID}/orders -- list user order list
POST /users/{userID}/orders -- user make an order
```

But uhm.. after reference some online documents, implicit userID will be identified after authentication phase, so here are the different designs by using **order** resource:

```
GET /orders/ --list user order list by user account(backend can get all)
GET /orders/{orderID}  --get orderID by userID
POST /orders/ -- user make an order.
```

with this define, when backend user want to list orders by user. Which method should I use?

```
GET /orders?user={userID} (user as query parameter) -- List order with userID
```

Or

```
GET /users/{userID}/orders
```

Pls advise me which one (**users** or **orders** resource) design is better, and why? 
Tks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which design is better depends on the use cases.

For example, let's assume two users:

1. Alice (`userID=1`)
2. Bob (`userID=2`)

Let's also say Alice has already authenticated so the backend has `userID=1` available somewhere.

1. If Alice wants to list her own orders, the shortest way would be

   ```
   GET /orders
   ```

   And have the backend user the available `userID`.
2. Let's say the request is suppose to retrieve Orders for the authenticated user.  What if Alice tries `/users/2/orders` - is she allowed to see Bob's orders?  What if Alice mistypes a lot and issues a query for `/users/2/`?
3. Final thing to consider - what if there are more attributes to search on in the future?  What if `userID` is removed from Orders from the future (let's say there's a new relation in the future like User --> Cart --> Order)?  Which URI scheme is easier to update?

So, there's no simple answer and it depends on your use cases.  In the case where it's just retrieving Orders, I'd recommend the going with `{GET|POST} /orders` for the most flexibility and simplicity.

Comment: for 2. It's ok if Alice has backend role, and have permission to see all orders, but if Alice is normal user, it will get 403 from service. I think your 3rd note is good reason for choosing URI pattern. Tks